# Calling batch with user creds not working in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, credentials

I have a powershell script that contains the following

```
$username = 'username'
$password = 'password'
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
start-process -FilePath $deploymentAppPath -Credential $cred
```

Yet when I execute this I get the following error.

```
start-process <<<<  -FilePath $deploymentAppPath -Credential $cred
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

While I don't think it is probably obvious, my end goal here is to call the batch file with the user credentials that I specify.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by removing the use of securestring.  Some things just don't seem to work with it in my experiences.

It appears that your process is local, so you're not transmitting the u/p over the wire.  Is the securestring really neccessary (considering that the u/p is in the script and available to whoever has perms to the script)?

Comment: when i remove secure string and just have -argumentlist @($username, $password) I get a username and password prompt

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not have the right version of windows powershell to use the `start-process` command. I ran this and it worked other than the obvious -FilePath error that I did not set. Where as you seem to be getting the basic 'command does not exist' exception. To check your version number use the `get-host` cmdlet. Run `get-host | select version` and if it outputs 1.0 to console you should go [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/30/download-windows-powershell.aspx) to get a 2.0 version.

Comment: the issue is that i have a script that uses plain commands found below and they work just fine. yet when called remotely they no longer function. example  `start-process $deploymentAppPath -verb runas -Wait` runs fine when executed locally, however returns the error of `Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied.` when run from a remote server. Even though powershell is v1.0

Comment: Ah I see, well definitly not a version error then. It seems you do not have the correct permissions on whatever computer you are trying to access. In order to execute this you are going to need local admin rights on that server.

Comment: I had my sysadmin make my an account with full access so that I could test. I guess I'm just confused as to how to call a batch file and pass it the username and password to call it with